# Is it possible to implement Admob in my app using Adobe Flash?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, admob, flash-cs5

I've made a working app to export for Android but I'm clueless about how to monetize it. Is it possible to implement Admob in my app? If so, could anyone tell me how or point me to the right direction if there is any tutorial out there about this topic. Keep in mind that I'm very new to programming and flash/AS3 but it's where I built it.

Comment: You can use native extension for Admob. Check out this https://github.com/lilili87222/admob-for-flash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As some of the comments required, I edited the response:

First of all, beaware of this when using flash mobile apps: https://forums.adobe.com/message/6053030

> The following is an "Official statement" I was given from Samsung
>   Support (07/31/2013):
>
> "Beginning August 15, 2012 we will use the configuration settings in
>   the Google Play Store to limit continued access to Flash Player
>   updates to only those devices that have Flash Player already
>   installed. Devices that do not have Flash Player already installed are
>   increasingly likely to be incompatible with Flash Player and will no
>   longer be able to install it from the Google Play Store after August
>   15th, 2012."
>
> And the "Official statement" I received from (Amazon) Kindle Support
>   (07/31/2013):
>
> "The Amazon Silk web browser on Kindle Fire 1st Generation supports
>   some, but not all, versions of Flash. Adobe Flash is pre-installed on
>   a 1st Generation Kindle Fire and is disabled by default.
>
> If you see a message to install Flash while using your Kindle Fire,
>   this means that the content you're attempting to view uses Flash. If
>   you want to view the content, you'll need to enable Flash through the
>   Silk settings menu.
>
> If a web page suffers from slow performance due to Flash, or you're
>   unable to view a web page with Flash enabled, we recommend switching
>   to mobile view when browsing a Flash-heavy website to see if that
>   solves your problem:
>
> Some popular websites may also have an app available. Check Amazon
>   Appstore, accessible through the Apps library on your Kindle Fire, for
>   availability.
>
> The Amazon Silk web browser on Kindle Fire 2nd Generation, Kindle Fire
>   HD 7", and Kindle Fire HD 8.9" doesn't support Flash.
>
> Some sites use alternative web technologies to Flash in their mobile
>   versions. We recommend switching to mobile view when browsing a
>   website with Flash content to see if that solves your problem:
>
> Some popular websites may also have an app available. Check Amazon
>   Appstore, accessible through the Apps or Games library on your Kindle
>   Fire, for availability."
>
> Android (Google) made the decision to remove access to Flash in the
>   Google Play store (August 15, 2012). Adobe  stopped development after
>   that, because it makes NO SENSE AT ALL to build and maintain Flash
>   Player for an OS and product line that it's INCOMPATIBLE WITH.... Get
>   it? On September 10 2013, Adobe released Flash Player 11.1.111.73 for
>   Android 2.x and 3.x and 11.1.115.81 for Android 4.0.x in keeping with
>   statements made in Adobe's publicly available Flash Roadmap. This
>   release was the final update release of Flash Player for the Android
>   operating system. 11.1.102.63 - the closest Desktop version to that -
>   was released March 5, 2012, so Adobe hung in there until it was no
>   longer worth the effort.
>
> Apple decided in 2006 that iOS would not run Flash, stating that it
>   was too hard on batteries, Android made the same decision, just six
>   years later, but for the same reason.
>
> Bottom line is THERE IS NO MORE FLASH PLAYER FOR ANDROID, and it was
>   an Android decision.
>
> I've personally spoken with sales people at Bestbuy, Office Depot, and
>   OfficeMax, and when I asked about Flash compatibility, NOT ONE PERSON
>   mentioned that Flash would no longer work, on Kindle or Galaxy
>   tablets. In fact, one guy said "Sure. I have a brand new Galaxy with
>   Flash Player on it. Facebook, YouTube... it all works." - THAT was an
>   outright lie.

You could try to use cordova with this webview (that may support flash) https://code.google.com/p/html5webview/. Then you could use this [cordova admob plugin](https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova) to show ads in your app.

If you are using other solutions, like Adobe air, you could take a look at [how to implement admob with adobe air](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/admob-ane-android.html).

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. Adobe AIR is still supported on iOS and Android, Adobe AIR is still Flash, so no, iOS and Android do support Flash.

Comment: not answering the question with opinion about something completely unrelated and false statements. Not recommending using Flash is the same as not recommending using Unity, it's irrelevant and has no place here.

Comment: Miquel, wessy is talking about AIR (something that's pretty obvious).  Flash publishes native apps for both IOS and Android in AIR.  We can help you understand the difference as well as adobe.com, yeahbutisitflash.com, gotoandlearn.com.

Comment: @moot for me it's not obvious that is talking about AIR, anyway the response includes comments for any case. Also if you have a better response to the question I encourage you to write an answer instead of yeahbutisitflash.com, gotoandlearn.com

Comment: I'm commenting on your answer because you answered incorrectly.  Your answer doesn't include comments for any case.  Yeahbutisitflash.com is for you to help you understand what AIR can do.  Wessy understands what AIR can do and wasn't asking that.

Comment: @moot really confusing: your first comment _"Miquel, wessy is talking about AIR (something that's pretty obvious)..."_ second comment _"... Wessy understands what AIR can do and wasn't asking that"_. Also this answer points to the correct places to respond the question for any case (something that just googling a little bit it can be easily found)